# How to create a unique ID for each database entry from multiple users

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012-express

I am working on a c# program that will be used by 20 to 60 users concurrently. The users will input information into various text fields and select from combo boxes and then save the information to a shared database. My question is how can I create a unique ID for each entry to the database so that they can later do a search by the ID? By preference I would like the ID to be less than 8 characters or digits. The database is designed in SQL Server 2012 Express.

Thanks for sharing!

Comment: unique id for each user who made the entry?

Comment: unique ID for each entry in DB or for each entry in table?

Comment: A unique ID for each entry in table! sorry i wasn't specific with that

Comment: Would you like to create your own format for the unique ID? e.i. ID000001, ID0000002, etc, etc.. or just use Identity column which auto increments so you won't have to worry about it?

Comment: I would love to use my own format if I can find some good pointers as to how I can program it so that each one is unique, otherwise I don't mind using an identity column

Comment: @BobEzuba Please mark the question answered or provide more information so we can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for an identity column.  It would give you a unique ID for every row that is inserted.  Identity columns are unique for each row and automatically increment themselves each time you create a row.

Here are two resources to help you out:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196(v=sql.80).aspx
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_column

Comment: Depending on the number of records, ident columns & keys also have a huge performance benefit when compared to varchar strings.

Comment: I created an identity column which will take care of auto increment. How do i get the ID of the inserted row? Please remember that there are multiple users adding to the same database at the same time.

Comment: @BobEzuba Use an output clause. And please mark my answer as correct.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your posts, I was able to use an identity column which turned out great i specified the starting position in the identity column. Thanks